# I need to insert XElement Data into DataBase Table , Which one is Good Approach (My XElement Data contains around 3-400k records)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I need to insert an XElement Data into DataBase Table , Which one is Good Approach ? (My XElement Data contains around 300-400k records)

Comment: Just to add for other readers (I had to google it) I believe a lakhs is 100,000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this much amount of data you will need to use [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx) class. The example there is quite descriptive on how to use it.

Comment: Yes It is suitable for my scenario.